# When I make the hdfs directories, it says: mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I want to install Hadoop 2.10.1 on ubuntu 20.04. When I want to make the HDFS directories based on the tutorial:[Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). It says that:

```
yarnhdoop@tcguoxing-QJC4:~/hadoop-2.10.1$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Then I want to make Name node leave safe mode, It says:

```
yarnhdoop@tcguoxing-QJC4:~/hadoop-2.10.1$ bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
safemode: Access denied for user yarnhdoop. Superuser privilege is required
```

So I think the user 'yarnhdoop' is not high enough and then I execute this command unser user 'root'. It says below:

```
root@tcguoxing-QJC4:/home/yarnhdoop/hadoop-2.10.1# bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
safemode: Access denied for user root. Superuser privilege is required
```

The step shown below have bothered several days.
[image]

Should I change to an older Hadoop version?

Comment: Was the `yarnhdoop` user created just for the Hadoop installation? If so, you should execute the commands on the tutorial from your _main_ user in your system.

Comment: I execute the commands from my main user: tcguoxing, it doesn't work.

Comment: The user who ran Hadoop processes is a superuser and (s)he is able to do anything. also `root` user in your system has nothing to do with Hadoop i.e. (s)he is not superuser in Hadoop also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have finger it out. Alll the previous operations were done through  the windows remote desktop with xrdp, which may cause permission problems. I directly operate my ubuntu system and it is no problem.